# SQL Server - CSV values against CSV id

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv

I have 2 tables, `TableA` in which I have `ID` and `Name` columns

```
id  name
1   Turret Punch Press
2   Laser Machine
3   Press Brake
4   Other machines
```

and `Table B` in which I am passing `Id` of `Table A` as CSV value like this

```
id  TableACSV
1   1,2
2   1,3
```

My query will be something like

```
Select 
    id, TableACSV 
from tableB 
where (--here i am having problem with query--)
```

The output I want should be like this

```
id  TableACSV
1   Turret Punch Press,Laser Machine
2   Turret Punch Press,Press Brake
```

I know this might be a bad practice to do .. but currently i need this ..

Comment: do you need the query for `MySQL` also ?

Comment: @Squirrel no only sql-server... i think i remove mysql tag

Comment: Google: `SQL Server group_concat`

Comment: use a CSV splitter (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) to split into rows, join to TableA and then use for xml path to concatenate back to CSV. Let me know if you need the query for this

Comment: Breaking 1st Normal Form is a very, very, very bad idea. Filtering becomes almost impossible and you'll have to perform very slow string manipulations. That If you want to store multiple  values for a many-to-many relation, use an intermediate table with the keys of both primary tables. If you want the output to the end user to contain comma-separated values, do the concatenation in the end-user application, your reporting tool or, worst case, your final query, A nice looking subreport though would be a *lot* nicer

Comment: @sagi i searched SQL Server group_concat but i think my case is different .. My TableACSV have CSV values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Agree with you.. I know its bad practice but since i have no other choice, i have to find some solution on this.

Comment: *Why* don't you have any other solution? What is the *actual* problem? CSV is the attempt to solve it, not the problem itself. *Creating* a comma-separated-value actually requires a lot more work that a proper design. Generating a subreport eg in SSRS or Crystal reports, or adding a loop in an MVC view is a *lot* easier and prettier than generating a comma-separated value too. Finally, if you want to generate the values in the query itself, search for "T-SQL string aggregate". There are some T-SQL options altough the simplest/fastest is to use SQLCLR

Comment: Look at it another way. Do you believe that you could *maintain* the resulting code? Split the list of values, join to a lookup table then reaggregate using the lookup text? What would happen if Table A grew to thousands of rows?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am working on this for reporting only.. the database design made by someone else.. as for opinion i am fully agree with you, maybe because this table is not having more then 500 records, the previous developer might have though this is good idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a CSV splitter [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  b.id, a.name
    FROM    TableB b
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(b.TableACSV, ',') c
    INNER JOIN TableA a on  c.Item  = a.id
)
SELECT  DISTINCT c.id, STUFF(d.name, 1, 1, '') AS TableACSV
FROM    CTE c
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT ',' + x.name
        FROM   CTE x
        WHERE  x.id = c.id
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) d (name)
```

Comment: In this case string-splitting is like applying Band-Aid to a belly stab. The OP has to split the IDs, join with the lookup source then re-aggregate the lookup values. In any case, Aaron Bertrand [makes a more thorough comparison](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) of the various methods to split strings. A CLR solution could probaly make the lookup directly, avoiding the split/join/reaggregate sequence.

Comment: its working on the given example....!!! need to test on my actual scenario..thanxx a lot